# Create a feed of someone's facebook wall

Tags: facebook, rss, feeds

Is there a way to create a feed of a friend's facebook wall updates such as status updates, shared links, uploaded photos...?

I have been using the following to subscribe to a facebook page:

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=<PAGE_ID>&format=rss20
```

But it doesn't work with profiles (using the profile numerical ID). I was able to generate what looks like a JSON of someone's photos using an access token generated via [developer tools](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<PROFILE_NAME>/photos?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

The resulting page looks like this:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "<ID>",
         "from": {
            "name": "<NAME>",
            "id": "<ID>"
         },
         "name": "Thuggin",
         "picture": "<LINK_TO_.JPG>",
         "source": "<LINK_TO_.JPG>",
         "height": 540,
         "width": 720,
         "images": [
            {
               "height": 720,
               "width": 960,
               "source": "<LINK_TO_.JPG>"
            },

         ...
```

I also tried all suggestion found on [this website](http://www.techlifeweb.com/2008/12/16/how-to-find-your-facebook-status-rss-feed/). No good.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook seems to be phasing out RSS feeds for information. Using the API (graph.facebook.com), is the most reasonable approach. You will need to know how to parse JSON via a programming language of your choice.

Comment: Seems fun. I'll do something this week and post it here as an answer. Thanks +1.

Comment: where is your answer @Alex ?, am seems looking for your answer i need the same result you are asking

Comment: @jothikannan I did not add an answer because the parser I made at the time didn't work properly and I didn't have the time to fix it and now I don't need this anymore. Feel free to try for yourself and add an answer, which might be useful for somebody else.